# Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollBy' in IE11 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill

I am using the following code to scroll scroll an element on mouseDown, and stop scrolling on mouseUp/mouseOut.

```
scrubby(xDir) {
    let dub = setInterval(() => {
      document.getElementById("chart").scrollBy(8 * xDir, 0);
    }, 10);

    this.setState({ dub: dub });
  }

  scrubbyStop() {
    const { dub } = this.state;
    if (dub !== null) {
      clearInterval(dub);
    }
    this.setState({ dub: null });
  }
```

This works everywhere except IE 11.  In IE 11 I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollBy'
```

When I console.log the element, the document.getElementById to ensure I am selecting the element.

I am using babel-polyfil

I see a lot of questions related to scrollTo, but not scrollBy.  Does anyone know any workarounds, polyfill or alternatives that might work for IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Babel polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) "will emulate a full ES2015+ environment". However, [`scrollBy`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollby) is not part of the ECMAScript specification and thus will not be polyfilled by Babel.
You need to add a proper polyfill by yourself, for example [smooth scroll behaviour polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) which also includes `scrollBy`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm over a year late to this question, but if anyone else is facing this issue and wants a solution that *only* fills in `scrollBy`, I'm using jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...and adding this to my page's JavaScript:

```
if(!window.scrollBy){
  window.scrollBy = function(x, y){
    if(x) $('html, body').scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + x);
    if(y) $('html, body').scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + y);
  };
}

if(!Element.prototype.scrollBy){
  Element.prototype.scrollBy = function(x, y){
    if(x) $(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft() + x);
    if(y) $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() + y);
  };
}
```

It's tested and working in IE 11.